# Symfony2 does not render php templates correctly

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with rendering PHP templates instead Twig templates in Symfony2. The problem is Symfony for some reason does not interpret PHP code in template. Instead of interpreting PHP blocks of code, Symfony renders them simply as plain text. I try to follow to the documentation and render form to template like [so.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form)
When I write in controller

```
return $this->render('MyStudyBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

form loads as I expect. But when I change "new.html.twig" to "new.html.php" and try to render form in php template - as a result I have HTML page, where php code simply showed like plain text. 
The question is why Symfony does not interpret blocks of php code in php templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable PHP templating engine.

In your *app/config/config.yml*:

```
framework:
     templating:    { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```

This might be helpful to you: [How to use PHP instead of Twig for Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html).

Comment: 5 edit are not quite enough!  Do one more and add a couple of spaces before templating just to make it valid yaml.

Comment: @Cerad You mean valid *Symfony2* yaml. :) Ruby habits... :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable PHP template engine fron the app/config.yml file, and save your template as .php and not .twig